# Move application to other frame and then back to previous

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, jpanel

I'm writing java applet.
I want to to open a new Frame with content actually stored in my Applet. I'm opening new Frame through the Button:

```
openInNew.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        createDialog();
    }
});

//this Function retrieves Frame for applet
public Frame getParentFrame( Component child )
{
    Container c = child.getParent();
    while ( c != null )
        {
        if ( c instanceof Frame )
            {
            return ( Frame ) c;
            }
        c = c.getParent();
        }
    return null;
}

private void createDialog()
{
Frame f=getParentFrame(openInNew); //openInNew is a button to Open a JDialog
    frame = new AppletFrame("NEW FRAME",jContentPane);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Here is the constructor for `AppletFrame`:

```
public AppletFrame(String string, JPanel jContentPane, Frame f) {
super(f,string);
    this.setContentPane(jContentPane);
    this.setSize(790, 650);

    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
        {
            removeAll();
            FileListViewer.destroyFrame();
        }
    });
}

public static void destroyFrame()
{
    jContentPane= (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
jContentPane.repaint();  /*this one should repaint the Applet View, but the result
              * is still the same. jContentPane is not null,
              * it is filled with acutal components. */
jContentPane.setVisible(true);
frame.dispose();
frame.setVisible(false);
frame=null;
}
```

My problem is that `jConentPane` is a reference, so immediately when I open my `AppletFrame` object, there is nothing stored in my basic Applet Frame. I wanted to set again `jContentPane` to `FileListViewer`, but I can't refer to non-static method in static `destroyFrame()`.

Comment: Won't calling `JComponent component = (JComponent) frame.getContentPane();` inside your `destroyFrame()` method will solve your purpose ? So now you got the latest reference of the `Content Pane`, so you can do what you want with this I guess. I couldn't understand the question though, that's why this foolish question from my side :(

Comment: BTW - `FileListViewer` Is that list of files on the site, or the user machine?

Comment: @nIcEcOw - nope, this didn't change me anything, I've uploaded my code again. @'Andrew Thomson' - this applet do not list files, just show load the list from server and show it to the user.

Comment: No no, it seems you doing it wrong. You got the `ContentPane` of your `JFrame`, inside `destroyFrame()`, but within the same method, you diposed the same `JFrame`, you have to call your `jAppletObject.getContentPane();` and not `jFrame.getContentPane();` because it's the former it seems to me that you need, not the latter :-) Moreover, if what you wrote is write, had you tried, `jContentPane.removeAll();` and then add `FileListViewer` to it again, then `revalidate()/repaint()` on your `ContentPane` for changes to take effect, if they already visible.

Comment: I wanted to upvote this question, just my limit is gone for today, i have to wait till tomorrow to do that :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- here no need to open a new [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) or another [Top Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) , use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead
- use [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) if you want to move one [Top Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) `toFront/toBack`

Comment: applet is embedded by `<applet code="FLV.class" archive="flv.jar" width="790" height="650"></applet>` tags on web page. My goal is to let user resize the newly opened window, so `CarLayout` is no use for me. When I use JDialog, this doesn't change antyhing for me (also when calling with ParentWindow reference). I'll edit my previous post for a second.

Comment: I think that JavaScript can do resize the J/Applet, maybe there is code for proporcionally or in percentage value to the browser